Django app with automated file upload from user local filesystem
I want to create a website based on Python and Django on the backend and Bootstrap, CSS, JQuery and Javascript on the frontend. The functionality will be somewhat like: user will provide a "Source_Path" from the user’s local filesystem irrespective of the OS used by the user. It will upload all the files from that folder to the server.
Is this possible? Can we make this automation?
I have tried using os. It is working on my local server, but in production, it is not working! I have deployed using apache2 web server.
Any suggestion can help!

I dont think that is possible. The files/folders have to be uploaded by the user to the browser as the browsers dont have access to the users file system for security reasons. So the idea of providing a path and the browser searching in the users file system for that path would be too unsecure.

What you are asking for seems like a file synchronisation/backup system like what Microsoft/Apple/Drop-box provides.
There is a reason these run natively rather than in-browser.
Browsers are designed to protect the user's operating system from the internet. So you will be hard pressed in getting access to the user's directories.
When you run Django locally, yes you will have access to the OS because Django is a "server" and is not designed to run on client's machines in production.
When you deploy it in production, django is no longer on your machine but on the server you deployed to. So any path you provide as a client in your browser won't actually exist on that server unlike when you ran django locally (the same machine).
So what can you do.
Well you could write an Electron app, which is designed to act like a browser & has elevated permissions on the host machine, however that will mean you might have to get people to download it instead of just going to a link in the browser.
Either way I don't see how you could build something that does what you want without getting the user to download something that has elevated permissions.

Even that will use the client to make uploads and is not as simple as giving a "Source_Path" on the filesystem to the server. Good answer, +1.

This is not possible.
In your localhost, the client and server are the same.
So by getting the path(from the client), you can access the whole filesystem(of the server).
But in the case of a different client-server, it is not possible, as you have the path of the client filesystem not access to it.
You can also test this using Ngrok, PC1 - create server, PC2 - upload path. It will fail
